# Can binary traffic go through a reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy

I need to implement a reverse proxy to filter external traffic. The inbound traffic is based on a binary protocol. As a result reverse proxy drops the traffic. Can we convert the binary traffic to http so it will be possible to go through the reverse proxy? 
Is it possible for this scenario to work somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Nginx and/or Apache will only be able to proxy HTTP traffic. You may want to look into HAproxy, which is able to proxy and load balance arbitrary TCP protocols.

Comment: Actually, HAProxy can't do UDP, but it does TCP and HTTP very well.

Comment: @GregL Ahh, that's right. I forgot we've had to write a couple custom UDP load balancers because of this. Thanks for the reminder.